# Error trying to use pyad to query accounts on another domain

Tags: python-2.7, flask, active-directory, pyad

I'm using [pyad 0.5.20](https://zakird.com/pyad/pyad.html#searching-active-directory) to do many operations on active directories which user can specify their connection details for example:

```
 pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="my.server", username=myusername, password=xxx,ssl=False,ldap_port=123)
```

And then i can for example retrieve a group by it's name:

```
group = pyad.adgroup.ADGroup.from_cn(groupname)
```

my problem is with the pyad.adquery.ADQuery() when i'm trying to use it after specifying connection details i got an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_defaults'
```

And here is the full code:

```
import pythoncom
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
import pyad.adquery
ad = Auth_Type_Config.query.filter_by(auth_type_id=2).first()
if ad:
    pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server=ad.host, username=ad.username,
                      password=ad.password, ssl=ad.is_ssl,
                      ldap_port=ad.port)
else:
    return jsonify({'msg': 'You must configure the authentication method for LDAP.'
                   , 'status': 'error'})

q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
where_clause = "SamAccountName = '{}'"
for (index, item) in enumerate(usernames, start=1):
    if index == 1:
        continue
    where_clause += " or SamAccountName = '{}'"

q.execute_query(attributes=['distinguishedName', 'mail', 'name',
                'SamAccountName'],
                where_clause=where_clause.format(*usernames),
                base_dn='CN=Users,DC=dsp,DC=local')

rows = []
for row in q.get_results():
    rows.append(row)
user = (rows[0] if len(rows) > 0 else None)
return rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's a little late, but the correct function seems to be **pyad.pyad_setdefaults** and not pyad.set_defaults

Comment: I am getting an error AttributeError: module 'pyad' has no attribute 'aduser', any ideas?